# add param via jquery to link_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a link and i need to add an extra param to it when user click, this param should be read at runtime from an input text, something like this

```
=link_to "Today", api_retrieve_index_path(campaign_id: "$('#campaign_id').val()", start: (Time.now-1.day).utc.iso8601, end: (Time.now).utc.iso8601), method: :post, remote: true
```

is there a way to accomplish this?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should do this on the client side, by observing the click action on the link:

```
$('a#my_link').on('click', function() { this.href = this.href + '&campaign_id=' + $('#campaign_id').val() }
```

Or for a modern, Turbolinks compatible, approach:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#my_link', function() { this.href = this.href + '&campaign_id=' + $('#campaign_id').val() }
```

This adds the campaign_id to the link when the user clicks it, but before the browser navigates the link.

Note that it's crude code because it assumes a query string is already in place and thus always adds an ampersand.